# What does javascript function return in the absence of a return statement?

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering, does a function without a return statement (or without hitting any return statements) return a value that is completely equivalent to false?

For example:

```
function foo(){};
!!foo();
```

This should return false if executed in firebug (but does not return anything if i just called foo();).

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Comment: JavaScript also has a second value that indicates absence of
value. The undefined value represents a deeper kind of absence. It is the value of variables that have not been initialized
and the value you get when you query the value of an object
property or array element that does not exist. The undefined
value is also returned by functions that have no return value,
and the value of function parameters for which no argument is
supplied. undefined is a predefined global variable

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A function without a return statement (or one that ends its execution without hitting one) will return [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Properties/undefined).

And if you use the unary negation operator twice on an `undefined` value, you will get `false`.

You are not seeing anything on the console because Firebug doesn't prints the result of an expression when it's undefined (just try typing `undefined;` at the console, and you will see nothing).

However if you call the [`console.log`](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) function directly, and you will be able to see it:

```
function foo(){}

console.log(foo()); // will show 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function a() {}
alert(a());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to find out, try this in firebug console:

```
alert((function(){})());
```