# Javascript function as a variable?

Tags: javascript

Here is a code example from Mozilla about javascript closures:

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

Why do you return inner function `displayName()` as a variable `displayName`, that is, without parentheses?

Comment: Because functions are objects too. `displayName` is the function, and `displayName()` calls the function `displayName` and returns its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return displayName()` would

1. invoke the alert at the line were `var myFunc` is set and
2. [return `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557754/what-does-javascript-function-return-in-the-absence-of-a-return-statement).

`return displayName` (without the parentheses) returns the function itself whereas the former (with parentheses) invokes the function and returns whatever the function itself returns.   As `function displayName` doesn't have an explicit return statement the implied return type is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

If `return displayName;` had the parenthesis then it would call the function displayName inside `makeFunc' as apposed to returning the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

In that code sample, `makeFunc` is being *called* (it has parentheses) and its return value is assigned to `myFunc`.

Inside that function, `return displayName` is *referring* to the function and returning it.

The end result is that `myFunc` is a function with a predefined scope (where `name="Mozilla"`), and can later be called.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, all functions are objects (of type `Function`). When you create a function, you're creating a new `Function` object and assigning it to a variable. In your case, you saved the function to the variable, `displayName`. If you want to return it, you put `return [variableName]`, just like with any other object.

When you put `()` after the name of a variable storing a `Function` object, you are invoking the function. It's much like doing `displayName.call(this)`. It's not exactly the same, as there are some important differences, but it's the same concept.

So if you put `return displayName()`, rather than returning a reference to the function itself, it would invoke the function and return whatever the function returned.