# Get object out of observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Why is m "undefined" in this code:

```
currentViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModel);
currentViewModel.getReport = function(reportId) {
    for(var i=0;i<currentViewModel.availableReports().length;i++) {
        if(currentViewModel.availableReports()[i].id == reportId) {
            var m = currentViewModel.availableReports()[i];
            return currentViewModel.availableReports()[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I call getReport() as an onclick event and I want to send the report object to a view (modal)  I can do a foreach on the availableReports and it's all there.  When I run through the debugger,  it loops through the array and finds the right one.  But why can't I pull it out of the array?  "m" remains undefined the the function returns undefined.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT: there is a follow up question here:**
[Can knockout.js wait to bind until an onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383742/can-knockout-js-wait-to-bind-until-an-onclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change `if(currentViewModel.availableReports()[i].id ...` to `if(currentViewModel.availableReports()[i].id() ...` because after mapping `id` will become an observable, i.e. function.

Updated code:

```
currentViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModel);
currentViewModel.getReport = function(reportId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < currentViewModel.availableReports().length; i++) {
        if (currentViewModel.availableReports()[i].id() == reportId) {
            var m = currentViewModel.availableReports()[i];
            return currentViewModel.availableReports()[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/j2zz47wv/).

Answer (score 0):

I'll repeat the *solution* from [@NikolayErmakov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35376650/419956) here, but want to add two things to get a more complete answer. You end with:

> ...`m` remains undefined and the function returns `undefined`.
>
> What am I missing here?

You're missing two things:

1. The `var m` bit of the first statement inside the `if` is [*hoisted*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top of the current scope (the top of the function). This is why the debugger can tell you what `m` is, even if you never reach the line of code it's on.
2. If a function invocation reaches the end of a function (as is the case for you, since you never go inside the `if`) without seeing an explicit `return` statement, [it will return `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557754/419956).

To better understand this, you should interpret your function like this:

```
currentViewModel.getReport = function(reportId) {
  var m;

  for (var i = 0; i < currentViewModel.availableReports().length; i++) {
    if (currentViewModel.availableReports()[i].id == reportId) {
      m = currentViewModel.availableReports()[i];
      return currentViewModel.availableReports()[i];
    }
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

Some people ([e.g. Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#variable%20declarations)) do recommend placing `var` statements at the top of a function, though it's a matter of style to some degree. I don't think many people explicitly return `undefined` at the end of a function, though in your case I *might* be explicit about that scenario and return `null` (or throw an Error even).

As promised, I'll repeat the actual solution, as I concur with the other answer:

- you need to invoke `id` as a function to get its value (because the `mapping` plugin will map to `observable()`s.

In addition:

- I'd retrieve the array only once
- I'd suggest using `===` instead of `==`

Here's my v0.5 version:

```
currentViewModel.getReport = function(reportId) {
    var m = null, reports = currentViewModel.availableReports();

    for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        if (reports[i].id() === reportId) {
            m = reports[i];
            return m;
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

But I'd optimize it to this v1.0:

```
currentViewModel.getReport = function(reportId) {
    var reports = currentViewModel.availableReports();

    for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        if (reports[i].id() === reportId) {
            return reports[i];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

For completeness, here's another version that utilizes `filter` on arrays:

```
currentViewModel.getReport = function(reportId) {
  var reports = currentViewModel.availableReports().filter(function(r) { return r.id() === reportId; });
  return reports.length >= 1 ? reports[0] : null;
}
```