# Can knockout.js wait to bind until an onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

This is a follow-up question from here: [Get observable from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376342/get-object-out-of-observable-array)

I now have an observable from a list, and I pass it to a modal for editing like this:

```
var report = currentViewModel.getReport(reportId);
ko.applyBindings(report,$("#"+targetDiv)[0]);
```

(targetDiv is the modal that I just loaded via ajax)

Now the modal shows up, and when I edit the report name, as soon as i loose focus, the name is changed in the original list.  Im starting to get the hang of this knockout, and that is exactly the behavior that I expect.

My question is, how do I get it to not do that until I click save? There is a cancel button on the modal and I would like for any changes to wait until I click save.  I have seen in the documentation that I can do this on a keypress,  but I want it on an onclick.

Anyway to do what I am after?

Comment: You would need to bind a different observable to the text input. Then on the save button do something like `data-bind="click: function () { report.name(inputObservable()) }"`. I'm not really sure of the structure of `report` so I'm making some assumptions with that code.

Comment: We'd need an actual (but preferably *minimal*) repro of your scenario to be able to help without having to guess at what might work for your situation, I'm afraid.

Comment: Expanding on what @DonovanM said, you need something like a 'displayedValue' observable and an 'editedValue' observable, and then some mechanism to update the former once the 'isBeingEdited' on the form is cancelled (e.g. a computed which is triggered by the change in this flag).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [protected observables](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html).

Comment: That needs to be a part of the core Knockout.  I will give that a try!