# Why do functions return `undefined` instead of `null` by default?

Tags: javascript, function

Why do JavaScript functions return `undefined` by default instead of `null`? Is this a totally arbitrary choice by the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), or is there a larger ECMAScript-behavior context in which this particular choice can be understood?

```
function a() {}
a();
// undefined
```

What is the difference between `null` and `undefined`? Is there a specification-based reason why is `undefined` more appropriate as a default return value, or was it an arbitrary choice?

Comment: Why would you expect `null` when the `undefined` value exists?

Comment: null is assigned manually.

Comment: IDK, I'm just asking, in PHP we have null as default return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does javascript function return in the absence of a return statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557754/what-does-javascript-function-return-in-the-absence-of-a-return-statement)

Comment: It's not duplicated, im asking why undefined instead of null

Comment: You need to ask the person who designed the language, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did a clarifying edited to possibly avoid closure; if you don't like it, feel free to roll back or edit more.

Comment: @FelixKling I did it, waiting for a answer. https://twitter.com/henricavalcante/status/712991622372298753

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc A closer duplicate might be [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript) This question asks about a specific consequence of that difference, but it's one that might be obvious once the difference between `null` and `undefined` is well understood.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The specification says of [`null`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-null-value) and [`undefined`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-undefined-value):

> **undefined value**
>
> primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value
>
> **null value**
>
> primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value

`undefined` represents a failure to assign a value. It is the *total absence* of a value. `null` represents the positive assertion of a non-value in an object context. `null` is intended to be used when an *object* is expected but the current value is no-object.

Given these two definitions, it seems obvious that `undefined` is the correct choice, since

1. functions can return values other than objects, and
2. a failure to specify a return value maps neatly onto a failure to assign a value

Answer (score 2):

That's part of the specification. If no explicit return value is returned from a given function, the return value will always be undefined.

> When a return statement is called in a function, the execution of this function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller. If the expression is omitted, undefined is returned instead

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: @HenriCavalcante — Why would you expect something that the code *doesn't define* to be `null` instead of `undefined`?

Comment: Its just the intended behavior. That's just the way the language was designed.  Undefined and Null are two separate types in the javascript language.

Answer (score 2):

Few key statements to answer your question

JavaScript does not have a void type, so every function must return a value. The default value is undefined, except for constructors, where the default return value is this.

undefined and null are two distinct types: undefined is a type itself (undefined) while null is defined.

So, if you have returned nothing then it has to be nothing i.e. undefined.

Comment: `null` is not an object, **null is for objects**

Comment: `null` is of type Null.

Answer (score 2):

Brendan Eich, creator of JavaScript, answered my tweet.

> @BrendanEich Why JavaScript function returns `undefined` by default instead of `null`? Is it just an specification or has a reason for that?

-- [Henri Cavalcante on Twitter](https://twitter.com/henricavalcante/status/712991622372298753)

> @henricavalcante null means no object, undefined means no value, wider type. Are you asking why both null & undefined in JS?

-- [Brendan Eich on Twitter](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/720863709103435780)

[image: Answer by Brendan Eich]

Answer (score 1):

The ECMAScript specification explicitly states that functions return `undefined` if no other return is specified. It's the default behaviour of the language.

See the last step in the [`[[Call]]` internal method specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist):

> ## 9.2.1 [[Call]] ( thisArgument, argumentsList)
>
> The [[Call]] internal method for an ECMAScript function object F is called with parameters thisArgument and argumentsList, a List of ECMAScript language values. The following steps are taken:
>
> …
>
> **11. Return NormalCompletion(undefined).**

Note that `null` and `undefined` are two distinct values in JavaScript. Again, according the [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-undefined-value):

> ## 4.3.10 undefined value
>
> primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value
>
> ## 4.3.12 null value
>
> primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value

Answer (score 0):

`null` is a defined value, there are two states for any variable, defined and undefined.

```
var a; // declared but undefined, has nothing in it; does not mean its null
var b = null; // declared and defined as null;
```

Every function in javascript has a implicit return: `return;` like in any other language to mark the end of the function. So it returns with nothing, which if you try to log, it will give you `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

If the fact that function comes as *undefined* is causing problems, you can use classes instead. They can be accessed the exact same way, but it will count as an *object*.