# Why do you get the exact same result whether you return `console.log()` or not?

Tags: javascript, console.log

Why does *calling* `console.log()`

```
function test1() {
  console.log('test1')
}

// or ES6
const test2 = () => { console.log('test2') }
```

---

Give the same results as *returning* `console.log()`

```
function test3() {
  return console.log('test3')
}

// or ES6
const test4 = () => console.log('test4')
```

---

```
test1() // -> test1 undefined
test2() // -> test2 undefined
test3() // -> test3 undefined
test4() // -> test4 undefined
```

While I understand a function without an *explicit* `return` will always return `undefined`, it seems counter-intuitive to me that returning the result of `console.log()` gives the exact same output.

Comment: What value are you expecting `console.log` to return and why?

Comment: Well, `console.log()` does return `undefined`? You can alternatively write `function test5() { console.log('test5'); return undefined; }` and it will be indistinguishable from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shall get a better understanding by looking at this:

```js
const realConsoleLog = console.log
console.log = (...val) => {
  realConsoleLog(...val)
  return val
}
const noReturn = () => { console.log('yep') }
const doesReturn = () => console.log('yep')
const a = noReturn()
const b = doesReturn()
console.log(`a is ${a}`)
console.log(`b is ${b}`)
```

If you ran the program, you'll notice that the `noReturn()` and `doesReturn()` functions get executed when you assign them to variables. So in the first case, the function is executing its block and then `return`s nothing, therefore a is `undefined`. But in the `doesReturn` function, you are actually executing the `console.log` method, which we've tweaked to return all the original arguments, and then returning the variable which the `console.log` returns. Since the original `console.log` does not return anything, so you get `undefined` as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have `void` return type specification, so whenever any executing context stops if there is no such explicit `return`, `undefined` will get returned.

To justify - `void` in JavaScript is an operator that evaluates the expression next to it. No matter which expression is evaluated, void always returns `undefined`

You can get this idea that whenever you use `console` in your browser, and even if you assign a value to a variable, you will see `undefined` get returned which is from `main` thread execution context return

Found this answer which has a good explanation to relate - [Why do functions return `undefined` instead of `null` by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201110/why-do-functions-return-undefined-instead-of-null-by-default)