# localStorage.removeItem function not removing items

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have created a function for deleting all game data from the localStorage but when attempting to use the function in the chrome developer console it returns `undefined` cant seem to figure out why

**EDIT:**
I forgot that return may confuse some veteran devs as to what I meant
My point is in the console it says `undefined` after running the function `HardReset()` and nothing in the game is actually reset

**EDIT:** The main issue is the function isnt actually removing the items from the storage

```js
/*
---------------------
Reset Entire Game
---------------------
*/

function HardReset(){
    localStorage.removeItem("money");
    localStorage.removeItem("level");
    localStorage.removeItem("exp");
    localStorage.removeItem("clickIncrement");
    localStorage.removeItem("clicksTotal");

    localStorage.removeItem("HTMLSupport");
    localStorage.removeItem("CSSSupport");

    localStorage.removeItem("HTMLCoderCost");
    localStorage.removeItem("HTMLCoderOwned");
    localStorage.removeItem("CSSCoderCost");
    localStorage.removeItem("CSSCoderOwned");
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem` has [__`No return value`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem#Returns)

Comment: Your function doesn't have a `return` statement, why do you expect it to return something other than `undefined`?

Comment: Which function are you calling in the dev console? `HardReset()` or `localStorage.removeItem()`?

Comment: **My point is in the console it says undefined after running the function HardReset()**. Why is that a problem? Your function doesn't return anything, so that's what the console says.

Comment: How are you determining that it's not actually removing the items from the storage? Can you make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the real problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Testing for support vs availability**

> Browsers that support localStorage will have a property on the window object named localStorage. However, for various reasons, just asserting that property exists may throw exceptions.
>
> If it does exist, that is still no guarantee that localStorage is
>   actually available, as various browsers offer settings that disable
>   localStorage. So a browser may support localStorage, but not make it
>   available to the scripts on the page.
>
> One example of that is Safari, which in Private Browsing mode gives us
>   an empty localStorage object with a quota of zero, effectively making
>   it unusable. Our feature detect should take these scenarios into
>   account.

[Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Take a look at that example Feature-detecting `localStorage` section on page.
Maybe the `localStorage` property is not available to the scripts on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of what you did you can just  change to

```
function HardReset(){
        localStorage.clear();
}
```

**localStorage.clear()** will clear everything in your localStorage

and also prove a return value.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

`localStorage.removeItem` has no return value.

Your function `HardReset` also has no return value.

[What does javascript function return in the absence of a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557754/what-does-javascript-function-return-in-the-absence-of-a-return-statement)

Comment: Even if it did return something, his `HardReset()` function isn't returning it.

Comment: @Barmar No receipt, no returns. Store policy.

Comment: You may need to read the values again, and reflect them in your elements displaying state data. There are more efficient ways of doing this outside the scope of this question, but your expecttions of data state and the reflection of that state may need challenging.