# Correct use of QUnit throw() assertion?

Tags: javascript, qunit

Using QUinit's [throw()](https://api.qunitjs.com/throws/) assertion I want to test that an error is thrown and the error message. I have the following function:

```
/**
 * Error function for Node.
 * @param {String} msg Error message.
 */
function NodeError (msg) {
  var that = this

  /**
   * Attribute for message.
   * @type {String}
   */
  this.msg = msg

  /**
   * Function rendering NodeError as a string.
   * @return {String} String representation of NodeError.
   */
  this.toString = function () {
    return that.msg
  }
}

/**
 * Node object. TODO Fill out.
 * @param {String} title Node title.
 * @throws {NodeError} If no title given
 */
function Node (title) {
  var that = this

  if (!title) {
    throw new Error('Error: no title given')
  }

  /**
   * Node title
   * @type {[type]}
   */
  this.title = title
}
```

And the following `QUnit` test:

```
QUnit.test('new Node w/o title throws error', function (assert) {
  assert.expect(1) // Expected number of assertions

  assert.throws(
    function () { new Node() },
    function (err) { err.toString() === 'Error: no title given' },
    'Error thrown'
  )
})
```

However, the Unit tests fails giving this:

```
Error thrown@ 0 ms
Expected:   
function( a ){
  [code]
}
Result:     
Error("Error: no title given")
Diff:   
function( a ){
  [code]
}Error("Error: no title given")
Source:     
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///Users/maasha/install/src/protwiz/test/test_pw_node.js:10:10)
```

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second function you pass to `assert.throws` should `return` something. You currently have a statement that evaluates to a boolean but the result is discarded. The function then [returns implicitly, thus returning `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557759/419956).

In addition, you're throwing `new Error(...)`, not a `NodeError`. You either need to change that, or just use `err.message`.

Here's a fixed version:

```js
function NodeError (msg) {
  var that = this;
  this.msg = msg;
  this.toString = function () {
    return that.msg;
  }
}

function Node (title) {
  var that = this;

  if (!title) {
    throw new NodeError('Error: no title given'); // <- CHANGED
  }

  this.title = title;
}


QUnit.test('new Node w/o title throws error', function (assert) {
  assert.expect(1);

  assert.throws(
    function () { new Node(); },
    function (err) { return err.toString() === 'Error: no title given' },  // <- CHANGED
    'Error thrown'
  );
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/1.16.0/qunit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/1.16.0/qunit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<div id="qunit"></div>
```

You might want to look into using a linting tool, which might catch this problem, as well as others (e.g. you have a *lot* of missing semi-colons, which can lead to [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/419956)).

Comment: Thanks, you are a darling!