# Retrieve data from Firebase database using react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get a data as a string?

```
getData() {
  firebase.database().ref('users/USER_UID/username').on('value', snap => snap.val())
}
  console.log(this.getData())
```

Why is it that when I do this, I get undefined? The `.ref()` is a direct connection to a key. I just want to get its value.

I don't want to do this:

```
getData() {
  firebase.database().ref('users/USER_UID/username').on('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()))
}
  console.log(this.getData())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `snap.val()` to a callback function:

```
getData(cb) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/USER_UID/username').on('value', snap => cb(snap.val()))
}
```

Then instead of `console.log(this.getData())` you can run `this.getData((val) => console.log(val))`

Comment: I tried that. It just gives me undefined.  Someone told me it has to do with it being asynchronous.  But why cant I get that return when I console log getData()?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1557759/772985) explains why `undefined` is being printed, because you weren't returning anything from the function.

Comment: so if I have a <Text> component and I want the value of that Text to be from a reference from my database.  Say its from 'usernameList/user/username'  and this ref () has a value of 'jef'  How do I set that?  The idea behind is to use a reference of database rather than duplicating it in other nodes.  I just want to use one node that is spread throughout all other nodes