# When do I use return in a function?

Tags: javascript

I learned that "return" in a function means the end of the function. 
However, I see sometimes there is a return and sometimes not. Isn't it supposed to use "return" for all functions?

Comment: well sometimes there is a need to exit and sometimes there is not.

Comment: And [What does javascript function return in the absence of a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557754/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `return` in two situations:

1. You need to exit the function before reaching the end.
2. You need to send a result to the caller.

If you reach the end of a function, it's as if the function ended with `return undefined;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit `return` from your function if it just does something without producing a value, and you don't need to exit early. You could also think of functions that don't have a `return` as having one implicitly at the end of the body. For example:

```
function noReturn() {
    console.log("Hello World");
}

function withReturn() {
    console.log("Hello World");
    return;
}

function withReturnUndefined() {
    console.log("Hello World");
    return undefined;
}
```

are identical.